# How long does the expansion last?

Tags: stellar-evolution

It is known that when a main sequence star consumes about 10% of the central hydrogen, the external envelope starts to expand leading the star to the phase of a red giant.

How long does this expansion lasts?

Comment: [Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) a better site for this question?